# Icon Arrow position in Twitter Bootstrap - Collapse Plugin

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a special request on my table collapse. When i click on the icon arrow down I need it going on the bottom of the div .accordion-group and not staying in the middle as in the Example. I hope that explanation is clear.

How can i achieve that?

Look the example

http://jsfiddle.net/STqCF/70/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just register individual click events on the up arrow and down arrow classes. They need to be live handlers (using JSON's "on") because the class will change after the code runs.

```
$('.icon-arrow-down').on('click', function() { move it to the bottom; });
$('.icon-arrow-up').on('click', function() { move it to the top; });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have maybe found an example to apply to my case.

http://jsfiddle.net/amosrivera/AYWku/

what do you think?

Thannks